# how to make a thread dependent on the other thread

Tags: java, multithreading

If 4 threads are running,and want that if t1 thread completes its instruction,and terminate,and want that t2 should also terminate after t1 terminates,even its instruction is not fully completed,while t3 and t4 are still running,that is it should only depend on t2,neither on t3 nor on t4.

Someone suggested me make t2 daemon,but that would make t2 dependent on t3 as well as on t4.Any one could help me out with an example how to do that?